# Css first div page full height

Tags: css

How can I make the first page of a one page website full height with a background image like this website? http://avathemes.com/HTML5/De7igner/image.php

Comment: You use Firebug or similar tool to inspect the page and learn from the css used.  It's pretty clear, if you do that.  They've just set the position of that div to absolute, and width / height to 100%

Comment: You could use CSS3 `background-size` property?:     

`background-size: 100% 100%;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the website in the link provided, they have only put the background image on only a specific part of the website (the countdown time). So if you want to follow them, you can put the required area in a wrapper div and then use the css3 background properties.

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

If you want the whole page to have a background, then you can just change the `.wrapper` selector to `body`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the vh unit?

> The vw and vh units stand for the percentage of the width and height
>   of the actual viewport. They can take a value between 0 and 100
>   according to the following rules:
>
> 100vw = 100% of viewport width 1vw = 1% of viewport width
>
> 100vh = 100% of viewport height 1vh = 1% of viewport height

```
.class_name
{
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the `background-size` property as in covered in this article http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/, check it out. Here is the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Br4fZ/ for what you wanted.